# filling column with another column value with condition

Tags: pandas

How do I fill root_cp_id column with cp_id of location that doesn't end with -.

The table I have

| cp_id | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1998 | 180 |
| 2294 | 180-1 |
| 2000 | 220 |
| 2150 | 2000 |
| 2001 | 240 |
| 2139 | 240-1 |
| 2157 | 120 |
| 2164 | 120-1 |
| 2244 | 120-2 |
| 2227 | 130 |

The expected result

| cp_id | root_cp_id | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | 1998 | 180 |
| 2294 | 1998 | 180-1 |
| 2000 | 2000 | 220 |
| 2150 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 2001 | 2001 | 240 |
| 2139 | 2001 | 240-1 |
| 2157 | 2157 | 120 |
| 2164 | 2157 | 120-1 |
| 2244 | 2157 | 120-2 |
| 2227 | 2227 | 130 |

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for missing values if exist `-` and then forward filling previous non NaNs values:

```
df['root_cp_id'] = df['cp_id'].mask(df['location'].str.contains('-')).ffill()
print (df)
   cp_id location  root_cp_id
0   1998      180      1998.0
1   2294    180-1      1998.0
2   2000      220      2000.0
3   2150     2000      2150.0
4   2001      240      2001.0
5   2139    240-1      2001.0
6   2157      120      2157.0
7   2164    120-1      2157.0
8   2244    120-2      2157.0
9   2227      130      2227.0
```

Or if need new second column use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(1, 'root_cp_id', df['cp_id'].mask(df['location'].str.contains('-')).ffill())
print (df)
   cp_id  root_cp_id location
0   1998      1998.0      180
1   2294      1998.0    180-1
2   2000      2000.0      220
3   2150      2150.0     2000
4   2001      2001.0      240
5   2139      2001.0    240-1
6   2157      2157.0      120
7   2164      2157.0    120-1
8   2244      2157.0    120-2
9   2227      2227.0      130
```

Comment: Sorry If wasn't clear, but Another column is not supposed to be used here

Comment: @Puzzlemaster - Unfortuantely not understand question. What is expected ouput?

Comment: updated the table. I want to fill root_cp_id using location's cp_id without -